# How to understand charge-$4e$ superconductivity?

Tags: condensed-matter, phase-transition, superconductivity

Why might electrons exhibit a preference for forming a charge-$4e$ condensate, as opposed to the conventional BCS charge-$2e$ condensate? Could superconductivity potentially arise from pairings within any even-electron clusters? Is the signature of charge-$4e$ or -$6e$ superconductivity proposed in the Kagome material CsV$_3$Sb$_5$ substantial enough to underpin the existence of such a condensate [[arXiv:2201.10352]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.10352)?